# Java ZonedDateTime MST to UTC conversion uses daylight savings

Tags: java, datetime, java-time, zoneddatetime, datetime-conversion

I need to convert the timestamp to UTC.
Timestamp has the MST timezone, which is specified in the timestamp

Examples of observed conversions:

- 2023-03-20 08:53:19 MST -> 2023-03-20T14:53:19     (-6)
- 2023-01-20 08:53:19 MST -> 2023-01-20T15:53:19     (-7)

```
static DateTimeFormatter EVENT_TIMESTAMP_FORMATTER = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss zzz");

static LocalDateTime timestampConverter(String timestamp) {
    return ZonedDateTime.parse(timestamp, EVENT_TIMESTAMP_FORMATTER)
            .withZoneSameInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC)
            .toLocalDateTime();
}
```

MDT offset from UTC is -6:00 hours

MST offset from UTC is -7:00 hours

Problem:
Java conversion treats MST as MDT which observe daylight saving

For example JS library doesn't have this problem:

```
console.log(new Date("2023-03-20 08:53:19 MST").toUTCString()); // Mon, 20 Mar 2023 15:53:19 GMT
```

Question:
Why logic is different from the standard behavior ?

Comment: In Java `ZoneInfo` has this code `aliases.put("MST", "America/Denver");`, instead of MST try to use the city instead

Comment: java's output is correct: the purpose of different names for the same TZ (MDT/MST in your case) is just to provide extra information to a **human** whether date/time specified is affected by DST or not.

Comment: This is happening because ZonedDateTime.parse uses ZonedDateTime.from, whose [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#from(java.time.temporal.TemporalAccessor)) states: “The conversion will first obtain a ZoneId from the temporal object, falling back to a ZoneOffset if necessary.”  So "MST" is converted to a ZoneId, which always has DST rules in effect.

Comment: Can't you fix that using [`DateTimeFormatterBuilder.appendZoneText(TextStyle, Set)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html#appendZoneText-java.time.format.TextStyle-java.util.Set-) giving America/Phoenix or another time zone not using summer time (DST)? I believe so and would recommend it.

Comment: Good proposal. Unfortunately this method adds `new ZoneTextPrinterParser` and not replace the existed class that has `preferredZone=null` which is trying to parse invalid index

Comment: I don’t think java.time is able to parse a summer time aware time zone name or abbreviation and give us the information whether it indicated summer time (DST) or not, which is probably a flaw in the design. But if we only need to make sure MST is parsed as MST without summer time, we can specify to prefer a zone that uses MST all year, for example America/Dawson_Creek or America/Fort_Nelson. You probably know already which time zone is appropriate for your situation.

Comment: While I don’t know how it’s implemented, [here is how to parse your texts using `DateTimeFormatterBuilder.appendZoneText(TextStyle, Set<ZoneId>)`](https://rextester.com/EDGDAL31804) and getting MST every time (offset -7) and never MDT (-6). We should of course leave out `zzz` form the format pattern string when specifying the zone in the other way. As you can see, the code works.

Comment: In my code I don’t use `LocalDateTime` for the UTC time, and I recommend that you don’t either. Use either an `Instant` or (richer) an `OffsetDateTime` in UTC. My code shows both options.

Comment: Stepping a step back you should not try to parse three letter time zone abbreviations. While I know of no other interpretation of MST than North American Mountain Standard Time (for example America/Edmonton), most of the most used abbreviations are ambiguous meaning that you cannot determine the conversion to UTC.

Answer (score 2):

This is happening because ZonedDateTime.parse uses ZonedDateTime.from, whose [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#from(java.time.temporal.TemporalAccessor)) states:

> The conversion will first obtain a ZoneId from the temporal object, falling back to a ZoneOffset if necessary.

So `MST` is converted to a ZoneId, which always has DST rules in effect.

I had hoped that [the version of DateTimeFormatterBuilder.appendZoneText](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html#appendZoneText(java.time.format.TextStyle,java.util.Set)) which accepts preferred zone overrides might help, but it doesn’t.  The preferred zones are only consulted for zone IDs which are considered ambiguous, and apparently MST is not considered ambiguous.

I couldn’t find any way for a single DateTimeFormatter to do what you want, but you can at least provide zone overrides when looking up a zone explicitly, using [the two-argument ZoneId.of method](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZoneId.html#of(java.lang.String,java.util.Map)):

```
static DateTimeFormatter EVENT_TIMESTAMP_FORMATTER = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

private static final Map<String, String> nonDSTOverrides = Map.of(
        "PST", "UTC-08:00",
        "MST", "UTC-07:00",
        "CST", "UTC-06:00",
        "EST", "UTC-05:00");

static LocalDateTime timestampConverter(String timestamp) {
    int lastSpace = timestamp.lastIndexOf(' ');
    if (lastSpace < 0) {
        throw new DateTimeParseException(
            "Text must contain a space before the timezone.", timestamp, 0);
    }

    String localPart = timestamp.substring(0, lastSpace);
    String zonePart = timestamp.substring(lastSpace + 1);

    return ZonedDateTime.of(
            LocalDateTime.parse(localPart, EVENT_TIMESTAMP_FORMATTER),
            ZoneId.of(zonePart, nonDSTOverrides))
        .withZoneSameInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC)
        .toLocalDateTime();
}
```

Comment: Good explanation. The overloaded `DateTimeFormatterBuilder.appendZoneText](TextStyle, Set<ZoneId>)` worked for me. I wonder why it did not for you. [Here’s my online demo](https://rextester.com/EDGDAL31804).

Comment: @OleV.V. I haven’t looked at the source, but I did see in the docs that the resolution of timezones is based on locale.  Perhaps MST is considered unambiguous for me since I’m using a US locale, but is considered ambiguous elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks for thinking along. Well, I explicitly specified `Locale.US;` on the formatter that worked for me. Java version, then? I believe I have had this working in earlier Java versions too. And a lot of zones are printed as MST (more than 5), so “not ambiguous” doesn’t make a lot of sense to me. I will keep wondering. :-) (Yes, locale-specific time zone names and abbreviations exist, which we should obviously be able to parse too.)

Comment: Did you simply get America/Denver even if you specified America/Arizona as preferred? (If you try parsing into a `ZonedDateTime` and printing it).

Comment: @OleV.V. Yes, I get America/Denver, but I’m not specifying America/Phoenix.  I was using ZoneId.of("MST", Map.of("MST", "UTC-07:00")), which I see now returns a ZoneId which is not associated with the ID "MST" at all.  Using America/Phoenix definitely solves this particular problem.  I guess I was hoping there was a general solution that could be applied to any timezone where one wished to suppress the use of DST.

Comment: I am not ruling out a general solution completely, but with java.time it will be complicated. And you would still have the problem of for example EST, EDT, CST, CDT and PST being ambiguous.

Comment: For a semi-general solution for North and Central American time zones only and contemporary dates only you could try a preferred set of time zones of Pacific/Honolulu (HST), America/Phoenix (MST), America/Merida (CST) and America/Panama (EST). I think that Alaska Time and Pacific Time nowhere come without daylight saving time, so we need not do anything special about them. You may additionally validate by formatting the parsed `ZonedDateTime` back and check that you get an identical string.

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost, let's define the error in the provided snippet.

I realize that the snippet above treats the MST timezone as MDT and does not take daylight saving into account. I hope you understand that.

Now, let's fix the issue, you can use the ZoneId class to specify the time zone with daylight saving. Use this updated version of the timestampConverter method and that should work for both MST and MDT:

```
static LocalDateTime timestampConverter(String timestamp) {
ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.parse(timestamp,EVENT_TIMESTAMP_FORMATTER);
    if(zonedDateTime.getZone().getRules().isDaylightSavings(zonedDateTime.toInstant())){
    zonedDateTime.toInstant().atZone(ZoneOffset.UTC).toLocalDateTime();
    }else{
        return zonedDateTime.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC).toLocalDateTime();
    }
}
```

This should fix the challenge you are currently going through! And if you need more clarification... Don't hesitate. Happy Coding!

Comment: The question is not asking how to compensate for the behavior.  The question is asking how to properly parse a string whose timezone ID explicitly states it is not in Daylight Saving Time.  (Side note: you should fix your answer’s formatting.)

Comment: *treats the MST timezone as MDT and does not take daylight saving into account* It may not have been crystal clear from the question, but the problem was the exact opposite: The code *takes* daylight saving time into account even in the case where *MST* states that it should not. So your code fixes nothing. Also your `if` part and your `else` part are equivalent, so your `if`/ `else` is useless.

Answer (score 0):

I used this code to achieve the -07:00 conversion all the time.

```
    LocalDateTime timestampConverter(String timestamp) {
        return ZonedDateTime.parse(timestamp, EVENT_TIMESTAMP_FORMATTER)
                // Java conversion treats MST as MDT which observe daylight saving
                .withZoneSameLocal(ZoneId.of(ZONE_OFFSET))
                .withZoneSameInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC)
                .toLocalDateTime();
    }
```

Comment: Thamks for the contribution. It's a pretty ugly solution IMHO. And if all you want is a `LocalDateTime`, this is more complicated than needed for that.

Comment: @OleV.V. I would be glad if you could provide a better *working* solution than this. Or at least a definition of why this is ugly

Comment: Thanks for the request. [Here is the way I recommend](https://rextester.com/EDGDAL31804). What I don’t like about your code is you are assuming offset -07:00 without validating that it said `MST` in the string. If the string some days comes with a different time zone, your conversion could be way off, and no one may notice or when they do, they will be at a loss to tell how and why. My code doesn’t validate either, but it converts correctly from other time zones too.